# How do I use a CloudFormation output value in a script with Ansible

Tags: ansible, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to set up some automation for a school project. The gist of it is:

- Install an EC2 instance via CloudFormation. Then

  - Use `cfn-init` to

    - Install a very basic Ansible configuration
    - Download an Ansible playbook from S3
    - Run said playbook to install a Redshift cluster via CloudFormation
    - Install some necessary packages
    - Install some necessary Python modules
    - Download a Python script that will
    - Connect to the Redshift database
    - Create a table
    - Use the `COPY` command to import data into the table

It all works up to the point of executing the script. Doing so manually works a treat, but that is because I can copy the created Redshift endpoint into the script for the database connection. The issue I have is that I don't know how to extract that output value from CloudFormation so it can be inserted it into the script for a fully automated (save the initial EC2 deployment) solution.

I see that Ansible has at least one means of doing so (`cloudformation_facts`, for instance), but I'm a bit foggy on how to implement it. I've looked at examples but it hasn't become any clearer. Without context I'm lost and so far all I've seen are standalone snippets.

Comment: Have you tried extracting the information about your cloudformation stack? I guess you can try adding some debug information as mentioned in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cloudformation_facts_module.html .

Comment: I figured out the `describe-stacks` and `describe-stack-resources` sub-commands to  the `aws cloudformation` cli command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to ensure an answer is listed:

I figured out the `describe-stacks` and `describe-stack-resources` sub-commands to the `aws cloudformation` cli command. Using these, I was able to track down the information I needed. In particular, I needed to access a role. This is the command that I used:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name=StackName --region=us-west-2 \ 
  --query 'Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey==`RedshiftClusterEndpointAddress`].OutputValue' \
  --output text
```

I first used the `describe-stacks` subcommand to get a list of my stacks. The relevant stack is the first in the list (an array) so I used `Stacks[0]` at the top of my query for the `describe-stack-recources` subcommand. I then used `Outputs` since I am interested in a value from the CloudFormation output list. I know the name of the key (RedshiftClusterEndpointAddress), so I used that as the parameter. I then used `OutputValue` to return the value of RedshiftClusterEndpointAddress.